# How to convert guid? to guid

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do I convert nullable guid (`guid?`) to a `guid`? My intention is to convert a list of nullable Guids to a Guid list.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the `??` operator:

```
public static class Extension
{
   public static Guid ToGuid(this Guid? source)
   {
       return source ?? Guid.Empty;
   }

   // more general implementation 
   public static T ValueOrDefault<T>(this Nullable<T> source) where T : struct
   {
       return source ?? default(T);
   }
}
```

You can do this:

```
Guid? x = null;
var g1 = x.ToGuid(); // same as var g1 = x ?? Guid.Empty;
var g2 = x.ValueOrDefault(); // use more general approach
```

If you have a a list and want to filter out the nulls you can write:

```
var list = new Guid?[] {
  Guid.NewGuid(),
  null,
  Guid.NewGuid()
};

var result = list
             .Where(x => x.HasValue) // comment this line if you want the nulls in the result
             .Select(x => x.ValueOrDefault())
             .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: thats for valid replies but My intention is to convert a list of nullable Guid to guid list. how can i do that?

Answer (score 15):

the `Nullable<T>.value` property?

Comment: I agree; no need to extend the type; if you know the nullable type contains a real Guid, just use the .Value property.

Answer (score 13):

Use this:

```
List<Guid?> listOfNullableGuids = ...
List<Guid> result = listOfNullableGuids.Select(g => g ?? Guid.Empty).ToList();
```

This is the simplest way. No need for an extension method for something that simple...

Answer (score 6):

```
new Guid(yourGUID.ToString())
```

Also a possible Solution..

Answer (score 1):

`type?` is short for `Nullable<type>`. See [the documentation for Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

being "id" a "Guid?"

Guid.Parse(id.ToString())

Get Guid null and create a guid by turning Guid null into String

Comment: Hi, thanks for your first answer!  Asking for clarification is best done as a comment to OP's question rather than in your answer.  Might be good to get clarity first before answering.